# Nexus 6P accepts touch input, but screen black. How can I pull off a file?

Tags: broken-screen, nexus-6p

My Nexus 6P is fully working other than that the screen doesn't light up at all. There is one audio file I have to get off it for work. I can unlock it with my pin by estimating where the numbers should be.

When I plug it in to my computer, the phone doesn't show up in file explorer. I'm using windows 10.

How can I get that file off?

Comment: Is USB debugging on before this?